# How to traverse push arrays if are not equal to values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My requirements are very simple: iterate over the array, use the object to determine the selected object, and then push it into the new array, but I don't know how to write it?

**Want the result as follows：**

```
[{
    key: 'name',
    name: "A",
  },
  {
    key: 'note',
    name: "C”,
  }
]
```

My code:

```js
var data = [{
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "A",
      "key": "name",
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "key": "title",
    }, {
      "name": "C",
      "key": "note",
    }, {
      "name": "D",
      "key": "desc",
    }],
    "show": [
      "title",
      "desc"
    ]
  }
}]

var arr = []
data[0].data.list.map(item => {
  data[0].data.show.forEach(prop => {
    if (prop !== item.key) {
      arr.push({
        key: item.key,
        name: item.name
      })
    }
  })
})

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question. It is unclear

Comment: Question is not clear, what are you trying to get. Why is B being skipped? in your desired results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the key if it is not includes in the `show` property and then push the object.

```js
var data = [{ data: { list: [{ name: "A", key: "name" }, { name: "B", key: "title" }, { name: "C", key: "note" }, { name: "D", key: "desc" }], show: ["title", "desc"] } }], 
    arr = [];

data[0].data.list.map(({ key, name }) => {
    if (!data[0].data.show.includes(key)) {
        arr.push({ key, name });
    }
});

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Albeit less readable, you could make this into a one liner by removing the if statement and using `!data[0].data.show.includes(key) && arr.push({ key, name })`

Comment: it goes even shorter without negation and logical OR.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `data[0].data.show.includes(key) || arr.push({ key, name })`

Comment: Ah yes, nice one

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let d=data[0].data;
let arr= d.list.filter(x=> !d.show.includes(x.key));
```

```js
var data = [{
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "A",
      "key": "name",
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "key": "title",
    }, {
      "name": "C",
      "key": "note",
    }, {
      "name": "D",
      "key": "desc",
    }],
    "show": [
      "title",
      "desc"
    ]
  }
}]

let d=data[0].data;
let arr= d.list.filter(x=> !d.show.includes(x.key));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = [{
      "data": {
        "list": [{
          "name": "A",
          "key": "name",
        }, {
          "name": "B",
          "key": "title",
        }, {
          "name": "C",
          "key": "note",
        }, {
          "name": "D",
          "key": "desc",
        }],
        "show": [
          "title",
          "desc"
        ]
      }
    }]

    var arr = []    

    data[0].data.list.forEach(keyValue=> !data[0].data.show.includes(keyValue.key) ? arr.push(keyValue): null)
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "A",
      "key": "name",
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "key": "title",
    }, {
      "name": "C",
      "key": "note",
    }, {
      "name": "D",
      "key": "desc",
    }],
    "show": [
      "title",
      "desc"
    ]
  }
}]

var arr = data[0].data.list.filter(item => data[0].data.show.every(props => props !== item.key))

console.log(arr);
```